# How to extract base Url from windows.parent.location.href in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using something windows.parent.location.href which returns https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
but i only need this part https://stackoverflow.com , i went through other's answer but i did'nt worked in my case so is there any way to achieve the above functionality,I am new javascript and was trying to the same and while debug got to know that there is something protocol in which http is stored and under host stackoverflow.com is stored but really don't how to implement that part

Your help will be appreciated 
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: for a regular window it is in: window.location.origin

Comment: @developer will it work for all browser i mean this webkit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type `window.location` or just `location` in your browser's console :

```
{
  "href": "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61459342/how-to-extract-base-url-from-windows-parent-location-href-in-javascript",
  "ancestorOrigins": {},
  "origin": "https://stackoverflow.com",
  "protocol": "https:",
  "host": "stackoverflow.com",
  "hostname": "stackoverflow.com",
  "port": "",
  "pathname": "/questions/61459342/how-to-extract-base-url-from-windows-parent-location-href-in-javascript",
  "search": "",
  "hash": ""
}
```

You can probably deduce how to extract `https://stackoverflow.com` :)